# Tikz pictures and captioning

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions

I am having trouble getting to have captions aligned under each picture.  I have tried the figure command, but that makes my two figures not align.  Any suggestions?

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize, yshift=0.6ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize, xshift=0.5ex}}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[h]{3in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
grid style={blue!50},
axis x line = center,
axis y line = center,
xmin = -5,   xmax = 5,
ymin = -5,  ymax = 5,
xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
grid = both,
]
\addplot[samples=300,domain=-2:2,ultra thick,color=blue]{x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\qquad
\begin{minipage}[h]{3in}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
grid style={blue!50},
axis x line = center,
axis y line = center,
xmin = -5,   xmax = 5,
ymin = -5,  ymax = 5,
xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
grid = both,
]
\addplot[samples=300,domain=-2:2,ultra thick,color=red]{x^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome -- use package `subcaption` and the code     `\captionof{figure}{Vision Algorithm Flowchart}`  -- please see the answer below

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
    positioning,
    calc,
    shapes.geometric,
    matrix}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\pgfplotsset{every x tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize, yshift=0.6ex}}
\pgfplotsset{every y tick label/.append style={font=\footnotesize, xshift=0.5ex}}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{minipage}[h]{3in}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                grid style={blue!50},
                axis x line = center,
                axis y line = center,
                xmin = -5,   xmax = 5,
                ymin = -5,  ymax = 5,
                xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
                ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
                grid = both,
                ]
                \addplot[samples=300,domain=-2:2,ultra thick,color=blue]{x^2};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{Vision Algorithm Flowchart}
    \end{minipage}
    \qquad
    \begin{minipage}[h]{3in}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                grid style={blue!50},
                axis x line = center,
                axis y line = center,
                xmin = -5,   xmax = 5,
                ymin = -5,  ymax = 5,
                xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
                ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
                grid = both,
                ]
                \addplot[samples=300,domain=-2:2,ultra thick,color=red]{x^3};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{Vision Algorithm Flowchart}
    \end{minipage}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: LEGEN (wait for it) DARY!! Thank you JS for your help!!!!!!

Comment: @NicholasBennett  would you like to accept the answer provided